# Widgets in home.php redirect to index.php

Tags: widgets, homepage

I have registered a widget in order to allow users to filter posts by category or write something in the search box, the problem is that my 'blog' page is 'home.php' because it is a single-page-site (in index.php I am loading all the content), when I pick up a category or click on search button it redirects to index.php, instead of remaining in home.php.

How can I change that behaviour?

Comment: What is the difference between those two templates? What are you showing on home.php and what is in index.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can change that behavior using [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter, but you shouldn't do that...

The main problem in here is that you use a static page as home and then, I guess, you use some custom WP_Query in it. It isn't very good idea. If you are showing posts on home page and want to modify the query, you should use `pre_get_posts` action to modify it...

It's also important to be aware of [template hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/).

Comment: Then how should I structure the site? I need an archive for the posts (which it should be index.php as I understood) but I need another for all the static pages.

Comment: @jos3m take a look at the template hierarchy - it should make some things a little bit clearer

Comment: I have reviewed it but yet I do not know clearly which is the best approach, I am very new in WordPress

Answer (score 0):

I have created 2 pages: front-page.php and index.php, the first to the static content and the second to the posts, then I assigned each page in Settings/Reading and that was all!